# Enable Push Notifications for Communities App - Salesforce as the User license for Permission Set

Tags: permission-sets, push-notification, mobile-publisher

In the Salesforce documentation [Enable Push Notifications for Communities App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=branded_apps_commun_api_enabled.htm&type=5) it says:

> Create a name for the permission set, select **Salesforce** as the User license then click Save.

But this is for sending `Push Notifications` to Community Users, not standard Salesforce users.

How are we meant to add Community Users into this `Permission Set` if we set the standard Salesforce license type?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall having to configure that custom Perm Set to get notifications to work. Try this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notif_builder.htm&type=5